# How to insert a repeating <td> in react using a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have multiple `<td>` repeating as it is shown in the sample code below. I want to put them in a function so that I can modularize my code. I cannot change anything in my code. Other solutions don't work as they are for something like `<td> {this.insertRow} </td>`. I want to put whole `<td>` in a function. If I do it straightaway, then `<td>` is rendered as a HTML string. Notice how my `<td>` has dynamic `className` and `doubleClick()`. That's why other solutions are not working. Only relevant code is shown here. I have more than 10 `<tr>` all having similar kind of structure with multiple `<td>`.

```
render() {

        return (
            <div>
            <table>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td className="class1">00</td>
                <td className={this.tdClass()} 
                    onDoubleClick={(e) => {this.show(e.target.innerText)}}
                > 
                    {values[index++]}
                </td>
                <td className={this.tdClass()} 
                    onDoubleClick={(e) => {this.show(e.target.innerText)}}
                > 
                    {values[index++]}
                </td>
                <td className={this.tdClass()} 
                    onDoubleClick={(e) => {this.show(e.target.innerText)}}
                > 
                    {values[index++]}
                </td>
                <td className={this.tdClass()} 
                    onDoubleClick={(e) => {this.show(e.target.innerText)}}
                > 
                    {values[index++]}
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td className="class1">00</td>
                <td className={this.tdClass()} 
                    onDoubleClick={(e) => {this.show(e.target.innerText)}}
                > 
                    {values[index++]}
                </td>
                <td className={this.tdClass()} 
                    onDoubleClick={(e) => {this.show(e.target.innerText)}}
                > 
                    {values[index++]}
                </td>
                <td className={this.tdClass()} 
                    onDoubleClick={(e) => {this.show(e.target.innerText)}}
                > 
                    {values[index++]}
                </td>
                <td className={this.tdClass()} 
                    onDoubleClick={(e) => {this.show(e.target.innerText)}}
                > 
                    {values[index++]}
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td className="class1">00</td>
                <td className={this.tdClass()} 
                    onDoubleClick={(e) => {this.show(e.target.innerText)}}
                > 
                    {values[index++]}
                </td>
                <td className={this.tdClass()} 
                    onDoubleClick={(e) => {this.show(e.target.innerText)}}
                > 
                    {values[index++]}
                </td>
                <td className={this.tdClass()} 
                    onDoubleClick={(e) => {this.show(e.target.innerText)}}
                > 
                    {values[index++]}
                </td>
                <td className={this.tdClass()} 
                    onDoubleClick={(e) => {this.show(e.target.innerText)}}
                > 
                    {values[index++]}
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            <div>
          )
 }
```

Comment: You want X identical `td` elements with only the wrapped text (`values[index++]`) being different? What/where is `index` defined? `array::map` is your friend.

Comment: why don't you use array.map() to render multiple <td> from your data object?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes. But className and onDoubleClick methods inside `<td>` are also repeating. So I want them in a function as well. `index` is defined in a global variable.

Comment: @Mohit can you share a link or an example of doing so? I saw some SO threads regarding that but they didn't seem to fit my requirement.

Comment: @AkhileshSingla I guess Drew Reese provided the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want X identical `td` elements for each value you can map the `values` object.

```
values.map((value, i) => (
  <td
    key={i} // or something unique to the value among siblings
    className={this.tdClass()} 
    onDoubleClick={(e) => {this.show(e.target.innerText)}}
  > 
   {value}
  </td>
))
```

If you need to "chunk" it up, you can pre-chunk it with array::slice, *then* map it.

[array::slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```
values.slice(startIndexInclusive, endIndexExclusive)
  .map((value, i) => (
    <td
      key={i} // or something unique to the value among siblings
      className={this.tdClass()} 
      onDoubleClick={(e) => {this.show(e.target.innerText)}}
    > 
     {value}
    </td>
  ))
```

If `this.tdClass` is dependent on global `index`, then you can increment it manually

```
values.slice(startIndexInclusive, endIndexExclusive)
  .map((value, i) => {
    index++;
    return (
      <td
        key={i}
        className={this.tdClass()} 
        onDoubleClick={(e) => {this.show(e.target.innerText)}}
      > 
       {value}
      </td>
    );
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem with the map function for me is that it will render all `<td>` altogether. `index++` is being used in my code so that each `<tr>` has 4 values from `values[]`. If I use map, then I can't render my table as required by my requirement.

Comment: So like if we could restrict map function to execute only 4 times such that index is also incremented for future rows, then my problem would be solved. Like first map function will work from index 0 to 3 for the first `<tr>`, then next map function from index 4 to 7 for the second `<tr>` and so on. Sorry, I am new to reactJS and Javascript.

Comment: Please include all requirements in the question then. Good questions tend to include all relevant details and full and complete code.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my question. I will try your solution now and will let you know.

Comment: @AkhileshSingla Updated my answer. An aside, it looks like you also have a lot of repeated code with each "Row", where each row is *just* a "chunk" of four indices from your values. That is also a prime candidate for DRY-ness.

Comment: It is working. But `this.tdClass()` is not being executed. Also in console it is giving warning "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."

I don't know about DRY-ness. Will look it up.

Comment: @AkhileshSingla I updated with key prop. I don't see any reason why `this.tdClass` would not be called now, if it's all still within the same component it should still work. **D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself Principle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Comment: Key warning is gone now. tdClass is in the same component. It is because my tdClass() require updated index value to make it work as required. Can you please suggest how can I do index++ in the map function without printing index in the table? Before values[index++] did the job for me.
Or any other way where we can send the current index of map function to tdClass?

Answer (score 1):

You can create new component for row and set props, like this:

```
const Row = (props) => {
  return <td className={props.tdClass} 
        onDoubleClick={(e) => {props.show(e.target.innerText)}}> 
        {props.value}
    </td>
}
```

See full example in playground: https://jscomplete.com/playground/s510805

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But Drew Resse solution worked for me after his inputs.